# CefSharp: browser window smaller than form and cut-off at top

Tags: cefsharp

I have built a simple app using CefSharp 53.0.1 in VisualStudio 2015 Community with a locally stored web app built on Bootstrap. (For reference the code is virtually identical to the OurCode tutorial: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application)

I have the main form maximized, and the CEF browser set to fill the form. However when I run the app, the browser is taking around 75% of the space vertically and 75% of the space horizontally.

Further, the top of the content is chopped off. It looks like you've scrolled down the page a bit, but it is not possible to scroll up any further.

I will post screenshots and a link to the code as soon as possible, but I hope someone might recognize this issue

Comment: Does the machine your running on have a `DPI > 100%`?

Comment: I will need to check, but highly likely. I have Cef.EnableHighDPISupport() in as a fix for the black bar at the top of the screen (as per https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1757) removing this, the black bar reappears but the browser shows correctly

Comment: You need a proper `app.manifest`. Read the last link I posted in that issue.